# Not letting Monger serialize

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, monger

I'm new to Clojure and I'm having issues with Monger.

I'm trying to user Monger with Friend. I have this ns:

```
(ns cemerick.friend-demo.users
  (:require [cemerick.friend.credentials :refer (hash-bcrypt)]))

(def users (atom {"friend" {:username "friend"
                            :password (hash-bcrypt "clojure")
                            :pin "1234" ;; only used by multi-factor
                            :roles #{::user}}
                  "friend-admin" {:username "friend-admin"
                                  :password (hash-bcrypt "clojure")
                                  :pin "1234" ;; only used by multi-factor
                                  :roles #{::admin}}
(derive ::admin ::user)
```

When I try to add this to database using Monger with

```
(mc/insert "users"  {:username "friend",
                     :password "$2a$10$YGcqRFL67J5NDo7hfkVslerDYc1iIGBy0js871wxnXxOvdvJZ4Aua",
                     :pin "1234",
                     :roles #{:cemerick.friend-demo.users/user}})
```

Monger serializes `#{:cemerick.friend-demo.users/user}` as `"user"` Is there any way to put that value as is or is there any way to change `"user"` to `#{:cemerick.friend-demo.users/user}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably returning `"user"` because the `name` function returns only the name.

```
(name :cemerick.friend-demo.users/user)
;=> "user"
```

You could get away with calling `str` on each keyword before inserting them into the database.

```
(str :cemerick.friend-demo.users/user)
;=> ":cemerick.friend-demo.users/user"
```